# Processing: Out of Memory error

Tags: java, user-interface, processing, out-of-memory

I'm using [Processing](http://processing.org/). Here is the entirety of my sketch:

```
import guicomponents.*;

PImage backgroundImage;

void setup() {      
  size(911, 715); 
  backgroundImage = loadImage("Floorplan.png");
}
void draw() {
  background(backgroundImage);
  GImageButton[] buttons = {
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10),
    new GImageButton(this, null, "wm.png", 1, 10, 10)
  };
}
```

(It is just a demo to illustrate the issue I'm having.) If this runs for long enough, an `OutOfMemoryError` will be generated:

```
An OutOfMemoryError means that your code is either using up too much memory
because of a bug (e.g. creating an array that's too large, or unintentionally
loading thousands of images), or that your sketch may need more memory to run.
If your sketch uses a lot of memory (for instance if it loads a lot of data files)
you can increase the memory available to your sketch using the Preferences window.
Exception in thread "Image Fetcher 2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
An OutOfMemoryError means that your code is either using up too much memory
because of a bug (e.g. creating an array that's too large, or unintentionally
loading thousands of images), or that your sketch may need more memory to run.
If your sketch uses a lot of memory (for instance if it loads a lot of data files)
you can increase the memory available to your sketch using the Preferences window.
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:41)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:458)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1015)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.createBufferedImage(ImageRepresentation.java:230)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.setPixels(ImageRepresentation.java:528)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageDecoder.setPixels(ImageDecoder.java:120)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.sendPixels(PNGImageDecoder.java:531)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:452)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:246)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at processing.core.PImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadImageMT(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(Unknown Source)
    at guicomponents.GImageButton.getImages(GImageButton.java:136)
    at guicomponents.GImageButton.<init>(GImageButton.java:100)
    at gimage_demo.draw(gimage_demo.java:35)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Why could this be happening? Doesn't the memory get garbage collected when the array passes out of scope at the end of `draw()`?

I encountered this problem when trying to make a button twitch. I couldn't find a way to change its location, so I just created a new one at the new location I wanted. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> **Why could this be happening? Doesn't the memory get garbage collected when the array passes out of scope at the end of draw()?**

The only thing guaranteed is that the `buttons` array is eligible for garbage collection when it passes out of scope. For the `GImageButton` objects, and it's members, it depends on what side-effects the `GImageButton` constructor has.

Make sure the constructor doesn't "register" itself on the first argument (`this` in your case), and that there's no caching going on, or that the `GImageButton` doesn't leak it's `this` reference from within the constructor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code (http://code.google.com/p/gui4processing/source/browse/trunk/GUI4Processing/src/guicomponents/G4P.java?r=331) shows that all `GImageButton` instances are stored in a static HashMap. I can't see a way to dispose of them (although I haven't looked that hard). Therefore they won't be eligible for Garbage Collection.

I expect the answer is to create the buttons once (e.g. in `setup`) and then use them in `draw` (unless you can find the equivalent of a `dispose()` method).